# What does it mean that Package installation is disabled in this version of RStudio?

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm trying to install tab plot package into R studio. My version is 0.98.1028 but

> install.packages("tab plot")
>   Error in install.packages : Package installation is disabled in this version of RStudio.

I tried going on github but I'm not sure what to download.

Comment: Check https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200554786-Problem-Installing-Packages

Answer (score 0):

You have different approaches:

(1) Load and install the newest RStudio Version
(2) Download the current developer version of tabplot via:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("tabplot", username="mtennekes", subdir="pkg")
```